# JTable memory leak when setting individual row heights

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, jtable

I need to show multi-line content in a JTable. The actual content is a collection of objects maintained in a custom model, which extends `DefaultTableModel` and generates cell content on the fly by overriding `getValueAt()`.

In order to have multi-line content, I have implemented a custom `TableCellRenderer`:

```
private class MultiLineCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
    public MultiLineCellRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(-1, 2, -1, 2));
        setRows(1);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        String text = value == null ? "" : value.toString();
        if (!getText().equals(text)) {
            setText(text);

            int newHeight = table.getRowHeight() * getLineCount();
            if (table.getRowHeight(row) != newHeight)
                table.setRowHeight(row, newHeight);
        }

        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Now if I populate the table with a few hundred rows (column count is 2), I see the AWT worker thread starting to max out one CPU core. At the same time, memory consuption goes up from ~100 MB to ten times that amount and further. That happens even if the application is not actually doing anything (no data loaded in the background, no user interaction) and stops only when I clear the collection from which the table gets its content.

By commenting out select sections of code, I have identified these lines as the culprit:

```
            int newHeight = table.getRowHeight() * getLineCount();
            if (table.getRowHeight(row) != newHeight)
                table.setRowHeight(row, newHeight);
```

If I comment out this section, all table rows have the same height (1 row of text), but memory consumption stays around ~100 MB.

If I replace these lines with a single call to `table.setRowHeight(row, 32)`, i.e. with a fixed value, memory consumption starts going up again indefinitely.

The following modification works, at the expense of all rows having the same height:

```
            int newHeight = getRowHeight() * getLineCount();
            if (table.getRowHeight() < newHeight)
                table.setRowHeight(newHeight);
```

Bottom line: it seems setting individual row heights in a JTable creates a massive memory leak. Am I doing something wrong, or have I encountered an actual bug? In the latter case, are there any known fixes/workarounds?

Comment: *I see the AWT worker thread starting to max out one CPU core.* - changing a property of the JTable will cause the table to repaint itself. You may be getting into an infinite loop. Have you verified how frequently the `table.setRowHeight(…)` method is invoked? Post a [mre] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: What monitoring tool do you use that shows high memory usage? Also, as @camickr said, without a [mcve], all we can do, is to guess.

Comment: `table.setRowHeight(…)` is invoked whenever `MultiLineCellRenderer#getTableCellRendererComponent()` is invoked, or when Swing invokes it internally. I do not call it anywhere else in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the row height triggers a redraw, which in turn triggers another call to the renderer. Therefore, it is important to set the row height only if it is different from the current one, in order to avoid an endles loop. This is what happens when you call `setRowHeight()` unconditionally, even with a fixed value.

A second issue is that each row comprises two cells, which may have different heights. The code above will set the row height to match the cell being rendered right now. When the other cell of that row gets rendered and has a different height, the row height gets changed again. That will trigger a redraw, also of the first column in the row. Since that will result in another height change, there’s the infine loop again.

Proof: the following code fixes this:

```
            int newHeight = table.getRowHeight() * getLineCount();
            if (table.getRowHeight(row) < newHeight)
                table.setRowHeight(row, newHeight);
```

Now the row height will only increase, but never decrease, thus breaking the infinite loop. Side effect: if the cell contents change and now occupy fewer rows than before, the row height will not change to reflect this.

Bottom line: rendering a JTable with multiline cells is non-trivial, and SO has quite a few buggy examples. The only working example I found (thanks to another SO post) is at https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue106.html.

Their solution is to store cell heights internally in the renderer (though this could also be done in the table model, whichever works best for your implementation). When calculating the height of a cell, store it, then get the maximum height of any cell in the row and use that. Also be sure to set the row height only if it differs from the current one.

That has fixed the memory leak/processor consumption issue, in addition to finally giving me a working example of how to calculate cell height properly.